# Das vs Der as it pertains to a Tiger

Tags: word-choice

Would there ever be a situation where, when referring to a Tiger, that *das Tiger* would be used instead of *der Tiger*?

Comment: No. Why would you think so?

Comment: No never, only in a composition like *Tigerjunges* ( young tiger), since all diminutives like *Tigerlein* are neuter.

Answer (score 5):

No. If your question is whether the word *Tiger* may be predeced by *das*, yes, that may happen:

It's either the different word *dass*, which introduces an *Objektsatz*:

> Das**s** Tiger Menschen fressen, kommt manchmal vor.

*Tigers preying men sometimes happen.*

Or its the introduction of a relative clause:

> Es ist ein Verhalten, **das** Tiger manchmal zeigen.

*It's a behaviour **which** Tigers show sometimes.*

But that *das* doesn't refer to *der Tiger* but *das Verhalten*.